# paygate payment transaction,angularjs/javascript,getting back after payment,http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, payment

I am new to angular js/javascript .
There is a need to do payment .
For this i am getting a secure url from the sever ,while opening that its navigating to paygate transaction (and the procedure goes on until the payment is made).
Now what i need is to get back again to my application after the payment is completed / how can i access the http headers or url of that particular page to get back from my application .(is there any possibility of running my code backend while the payment is going on ?)

just by using
     window.location.href="secure ulr";
this doesn't make to access / i can't able to access.

how to do this whole procedure in javascript .
I don't know how to do .
Any help will be appreciaed.please.

Comment: can you post some of your relevant code?

Comment: Normally payment gateways allow you to specify the HTTP(S) address that the user should be redirected to after payment is complete on their end.

Comment: still didn't implemented Now i am just having that url ,after opening that its navigating to payment pages .Now how can i access that from my application ..Do i need to use ajax to open and access parameters ?

Comment: I think just by using window.location to navigate doesn't return me anything to handle.

Comment: can you please give me any suggestion.